# ULS realtime logging not returning anything

Tags: 2013, logging, uls

So, i was out of office for one day and Sharepoint gives up on me.

I'm trying to use ULS realtime feed to see whats going on but it returns zero data. While navigating down to *C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS* i can see that SharePoint is still logging data that are up to date, and i got plenty of space on the drive, and the logging is set to not grow above 3 GB.

One thing i noticed however is that on my Dev environment, all the log files got the file extension **.log** and in production they do not have any extension at all, just a name. ( Servername-Date-Time ) instead of Servername-Date-Time.Log.

Could it be that ULS cant read those files without the extension? Anyone else had this problem? I can still open a specific log-file to manually read it from ULS but this does not help me much.

Comment: May be your prod server is set not show file extensions, you can change this by going to Folder Options > View > Hide extensions for known file types, Uncheck the checkbox. Are you using any tools to see ULS realtime feed? hope you haven't applied any filters on it.

Comment: Which tool are you using to view ULS log files?

Comment: Xgencoder: Correct, the file extension was not checked, but that did not change anything. I'm using UlsViewer. And there is no filter, i just compared the configurations to dev environment and they are all the same. No filters applied.

Comment: Aanchal: UlsViewer. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020